# Authentication issue: spring-boot application with postgresql running on docker

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I try to connect my spring boot application and PostgreSQL which is in a docker container. 
When I launch my docker-compose, docker create a container and database with the user I set it in this file. 
every thing is ok until here.

But when I try to connect my spring application and this container I get this error :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: authentification par mot de passe échouée pour l'utilisateur  « postgres » (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
```

The message is in French, In general it can't connect to my database with that user postgres.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-password}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-dbname}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
```

and my application.property

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

any one have an idea about this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I assume it's an issue with the defined network. As per default standalone containers use the default network / bridge from docker which offers basic networking functionality. But since you defined a custom network, I assume your spring-app which is running on your host system is not able to reach your container.

Try to remove the networks part and try it.